Error: Invalid provider when creating a Deployer instance zksync-web3
I keep getting an error Invalid provider when I try to create a deployer instance, here is the code:

const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
const {Wallet} = require("zksync-web3")
const {Deployer} = require('@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy')
require('dotenv').config()
const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

module.exports = async function deploy(hre) {

  try {
    const signer = new Wallet(privateKey)
    console.log(signer)
    const deployer = new Deployer(hre, signer)

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Deployment failed:", error)
  }
}

I dont know what the issue is, but supposedly HardhatRuntimeEnvironment should have added that provider, I tried correcting the network in config file as follows:
networks: {

sepolia: {
  url: `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${infuraApi}`,
  accounts: [`0x${privateKey}`]
},
zkSyncDeploy: {
  url: "https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev",
  zksync:true,
  ethNetwork: "goerli"
}

But still I keep getting the same error

Turns out I was using the deprecated "zksync-web3" and should have used "zksync-ethers", now it works just fine with changing the following line:
const {Wallet} = require("zksync-web3")

To
const {Wallet} = require("zksync-ethers")

to install zksync-ethers run command: npm install zksync-ethers
